# What useful data can be obtained by using building and flying a scale model of a fighter aircraft design?

Tags: aircraft-design

The use of scale models in the design of modern fighter aircraft seems to be rare, wind tunnel models and software is used instead. Is building and flying a scale model of a jet fighter or trainer design an out-dated practice?

NASA tested the HIMAT concept in the 1990s.

[HIMAT concept.](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4406/chap8.html)

Comment: While scale models may teach us a lot about flight characteristics, I would imagine that scale models are not used _because_ wind tunnels & [CFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) have improved so much, even over the last 20 years, that building & flying scales is too expensive and time consuming in comparison.

Comment: Not only about fighters, since NASA built a blended wing body airliner concept. The use of flying scale models is more or less unheard of in designing civillian airliners.